# ACAM PS09: Strain Gauge Stress Analysis

Tags: microcontroller, strain-gage

I've been working on implementing strain gauge measurements at my company for some stress analysis. There's a chip that I think works the best for our application. It's the PS09 by ACAM. However, there are some problems I've run into concerning the on-board RAM and the consistency of its measurements.

For me, the appealing things about the device are its low-power, temperature 
compensation, and SPI communication. These are all things I'm looking for.
So, I was hoping to run some ideas by anyone that has touched on this kind of device before.

There's a lack of talk about the PS09 online. I don't know if that's indicative of lack of usability and/or no one actually knows about it.

**Has anyone worked with the PS09 chip?**

Here's what I believe is the most recent datasheet: http://www.acam.de/fileadmin/Download/pdf/PICOSTRAIN/English/DB_PS09_Vol1_en.pdf

Please let me know if other details are needed, and I will try to provide them. (Is there, perhaps, another question that might be related to this?)

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to successfully work on the PS09. If anyone sees this and would like to know about the PS09, I will respond when possible.

Comment: yes please, kindly elaborate your finding.

Comment: its 2022 and still not a lot of details are available.